# How to use the filter criteria in API?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, rest

This snippet works fine and I get successful reponse[200].

```
res = session.get("https://{domain}/learning/odatav4/public/user/learningHistory/v1/learninghistorys?$filter=criteria/personGUID eq '96545645F'")
print (res.url)

"https://{domain}learning/odatav4/public/user/learningHistory/v1/learninghistorys?$filter=criteria/personGUID%20eq%20'96545645F'"
```

When I pass the parameter(s), I get an error.

```
{'error': {'code': None,
  'message': "The types 'Edm.Boolean' and 'Edm.String' are not compatible."}}
```

```
person_id = '96545645F'
params = {
    '$filter': f"criteria/personGUID eq '{person_id}'"
}
res = session.get("https://{domain}/learning/odatav4/public/user/learningHistory/v1/learninghistorys", params = params)
print (res)

'https://{domain}/learning/odatav4/public/user/learningHistory/v1/learninghistorys?%24filter=criteria%2FpersonGUID+eq+%2796545645F%27'
```

Comment: can you please tell use the error?

Comment: Keys and values passed in via params get URL-encoded. If you don't want that, manually add them to the URL (e.g. use string formatting), see e.g. https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/794#issuecomment-7859131.

Comment: @Builditluc, added the error in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add your parameters in URL because requests do not encode parameters in params attribute!

Try this:

```
person_id = '96545645F'
url = f"https://{domain}/learning/odatav4/public/user/learningHistory/v1/learninghistorys?$filter=criteria/personGUID eq '{person_id}'"
res = session.get(url)
print(res)
```